# get value for dynamic checkbox in struts 1.2

Tags: struts

Currently I am working with the project in struts1.2 which needs dynamically generated checkboxes and i have generated dynamic checkboxes but i am facing problem with getting the vaue of selected checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

from the action class? - its on the form object passed as a parameter.